# Adding select field after order notes for WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add a bunch of custom fields at the end of the checkout form that collects additional data we'd need to process an order.

This is what I have:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'student_info_fields' );

function student_info_fields( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="student_info"><span>The following information below will be used to create an account.</span>';

    //This adds a student_name field 
    woocommerce_form_field( 'student_name', array(
        'type'        => 'text',
        'class'       => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label'       => __('Student Name'),
        'placeholder' => __('eg: "John Smith", "Johnny", etc'),
        'required'    => 'true',
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'student_name' ));

    /* I have two other text fields here that follow the same syntax as student_name */

    //This adds a student_gender field 
    woocommerce_form_field( 'student_gender', array(
       'type'        => 'select',
       'label'       => __('Gender', 'woocommerce'),
       'placeholder' => _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
       'required'    => 'true',
       'options'     => array(
          'male' => __('Male', 'woocommerce' ),
          'female' => __('Female', 'woocommerce' )
       ),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'student_gender' ));

    echo '</div>';

}
```

The text fields all seem to work, but when I add the student_gender field, my page breaks (all white screen). I'm a little skeeved out by calling the `options` array within the `student_gender` array, as well as calling the `$checkout ->get_value...` line after I declare each field, but I simply don't know what to do.

Any direction you can give me would be so helpful to cracking this nut. Thanks for sticking with it!

Comment: Look at your server's error log to know the exact error. Probably this will give you all the information you need. If not, come back and paste the error in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at it and figured out what I was screwing up. That is to say, it pointed me toward my `label` declaration, which I don't think was using the proper syntax.

I changed my code to:

```
    //This adds a student_gender field 
woocommerce_form_field( 'student_gender', array(
    'type'        => 'select',
    'label'       => __('Student Gender'),
    'placeholder' => _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'    => 'true',
    'options'     => array(
           'male' => __('Male', 'woocommerce' ),
           'female' => __('Female', 'woocommerce' )
    ),
), $checkout->get_value( 'student_grade' ));
```